# Is there stubs and tests for data structures?

Tags: data-structures

I want to implement all of the data structures from scratch but testing them is not an easy task. So, I wanted to ask if any of you know repository containing Class, Method Stubs for popular data structures and also their tests. Especially, unit tests are of a great importance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a great repo which contains not only DS implementations also some popular algorithms too. On top of that, it has a high unit test coverage. I'll use it: [DSA by William Fiset](https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms)

Even better, there are complementary video tutorials and they are freely available on YouTube: [DS Tutorial by William Fiset @ FreeCodeCamp](https://youtu.be/RBSGKlAvoiM)

Just wanted to post this answer here so someone who needs it doesn't waste days looking for it like I did.

---

**Good luck!**

Comment: I could not find test cases there. Could you please help.

Comment: They are in the src/test folder: https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms/tree/master/src/test/java/com/williamfiset/algorithms/datastructures